# javascript appended to div is coming as a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a java script

```
$('#linegraph').append(sparkLineData);
```

where the value of sparkLineData is `1,2,3,4,5,6,7`

where

```
<div id="linegraph"></div>
```

where in this div i need to append the values like

```
<div id="linegraph">1,2,3,4,5,6,7</div>
```

but why is it coming as

```
<div id="linegraph">"1,2,3,4,5,6,7"</div>
```

**why does it happen like this?** It seeems like it is appending as a string.Is there any solution for this to remove the `" "` ?

Comment: you probably need $("#sparkLineData").html(sparkLineData)

Comment: This shouldn't be the case

Comment: works just fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4a4nj/1/ - the only I can see it happening is if the string itself has an enclosing `"` in it like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/4a4nj/2/

Comment: Can you share how the value of `sparkLineData` variable is constructed

Comment: So is `sparkLineData` an array or a string?

Comment: @A.Wolff irrespective whether it is an array or string the chances of the said problem is almost nil unless the string value itself is enclosed in `""`

Comment: @ArunPJohny ya correct. I really don't understand issue here and as suggested by Rory McCrossan, maybe OP could provide a example which replicates his issue, if it is not too much asked...

Comment: @A.Wolff may be a close vote the right answer

Comment: @ArunPJohny       sparkLineData=sparkLineData+parseInt(thistransAmount[j])+",";
   this constructs the sparkLineData

Comment: @user3163619 Can you replicate the problem in jsfiddle.net ? Also is the end result of sparkLineData "\"1,2,3,4,5,6,7\""?

Comment: @user3163619 can you provide a little more context... like more code

Comment: Ill make a fiddle just a second @ArunPJohny

Comment: @user3163619 that will be great...

Comment: @user3163619 so are you able to replicate your issue in jsfiddle?

Comment: @ArunPJohny  http://jsfiddle.net/8E5KL/1/  here in the js you can find while inspecting in chrome that there is "" for each value so whatsoever..I want to remove the ",if I use .text() it removes the value but doesnt append it to the div

Comment: @ArunPJohny or just use `text()` http://jsfiddle.net/8E5KL/3/ But wait, OP provided jsfiddle is more confusing than helping in understanding issue... " you can find while inspecting in chrome that there is "" for each value" What and how? If you are using the data-* attributes to create an array or string, just let us know. Again, could you replicate issue in jsfiddle, your previous jsfiddle doesn't help in any way

Comment: @A.Wolff yes I think it is a lost cause

Answer (score 3):

Use `text()` instead:

```
$('#linegraph').text(sparkLineData);
```

Also, shouldn't the selector be `#sparkLineData`?

Comment: but append should work the same here, right?! PS: downvoter, please elaborate?!

Comment: @A.Wolff no it won't: http://jsfiddle.net/8E5KL/. Although I can't recreate OPs exact case.

Comment: "the value of sparkLineData is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7" I was thinking about a string, otherwise appending array to HTML element won't give 'similar' result. But ya, question is unclear

Comment: In that case you have something odd elsewhere in your code causing the problem. You can see in the fiddle I posted above that this does work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.text()`

Try this

```
$("#linegraph").html(sparkLineData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

```
 $('#linegraph').append(sparkLineData);
```

change to

```
 $('#linegraph').text('Your data');
```

Answer (score -1):

Try jquery replace power

```
$('#linegraph').append(sparkLineData).replace('"','');
```

Comment: no you cant use replace on an object, and replace function is not jQuery it's javascript

Comment: Rory McCrossan : Yes you are right. replace function is javascript.  Thanks for the correction :)